# Azure Yaml Pipeline - Update Workitems from multiple Repositories

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In a nutshell, I am looking to get a list of work items linked to a git branch.

In more detail

I am working with 4 repositories that I add as resources to my pipeline

```
  - repository: Cms # code repository
    name: <ProjectName>/Cms
    type: git
    ref: develop2022
  - repository: QA-Automation # Automated Testing Repo
    name: <ProjectName>/QA-Automation
    type: git
    ref: main
  - repository: TdsWDPExplorer # Generate Reports Repo
    name: <ProjectName>/TdsWDPExplorer
    type: git
    ref: master
```

The Pipeline yaml files them self's are in the 4th Repo and checked out as self

```
    - checkout: Self
      path: s/DE-DevOps
```

I am trying to update the work items associated with the Cms Repository.
I tried using the Workitem Updater task https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater

But it only sees the workitems associated with the Repository holding the yaml Files (Self).
I also looked at the API to get a list of the work items.

_apis/git/repositories//refs?filter=heads%2fBRANCHNAME&includeLinks=true
Gives me details to a branch but I didn't find the linked work items

Also looking at the workitem I dint see that info
_apis/wit/workitems?ids=ITEM-ID's&$expand=all&api-version=6.0

I am thinking it might be somewhere in _apis/wit/reporting/workitemlinks but haven been able to get the info.

Comment: Can you share how you’ve defined the step for the BlueBasher task? That might help show what is going on. Also if you’ve provided it a query, when you run that manually, does it show the results you expect?

Comment: Hi Richard,

I am running the task like:
`
    - task: WorkItemUpdater@2
      inputs:
        workItemType: 'Bug, Task, User Story'
        workitemsSource: 'Build'
        updateAssignedTo: 'Never'
        addTags: 'On_UAT'
`
It picks up the workitems from the repository that the pipeline is loaded from but not from the repositories that have been added as resources

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer that works for me, in a response to [Obtain all work items from Azure DevOps that have been merged into a branch via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69450487/obtain-all-work-items-from-azure-devops-that-have-been-merged-into-a-branch-via)

we link the work items to pull requests, I can use the API to query the pull requests in to the given branch and get the linked work items like:

https://dev.azure.com/Organisation/Project/_apis/git/repositories/Cms/pullrequests?searchCriteria.status=completed&searchCriteria.targetRefName=refs/heads/BRANCHNAME&api-version=6.0

I should now be able to extract the ID's and pass them in a PS loop to the Item Updater Task https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BlueBasher.bluebasher-workitemupdater or using the API to update the workitem

There is also the option to call the API for the pipeline run info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#runresources

But I didn't see a way to extract the work items but the information must be somewhere there as well because I can see the work items listed in the pipeline view by resource

[image: screen shot]